# What is the correct way to update state and render the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am just wondered why in some cases the state does not lead to render the component.

This example doesn't render the component:

```
const [items,setItems] = useState({
    item_name:'',
    item_price:'',
    color:''
})

some_method = (new_item_name) => {
    items.item_name=new_item_name;
    setItems(items);
}
```

**Is it wrong to do it this way?**

```
const [is_rendered, set_is_rendered] = useState(false);

const [items,setItems] = useState({
    item_name:'',
    item_price:'',
    color:''
})

some_method = (new_item_name) => {

    items.item_name=new_item_name;
    setItems(items);

    set_is_rendered(!is_rendered);
}
```

Since boolean values always renders the component so I supposed to create a new `state` to render the component when need to do so.

Comment: React will update the component on every change in the state, so having `is_rendered` is redundant and will cause your component to be rendered twice (a first time because you changed `items`, a second time because `is_rendered` has changed.) I suggest you to add some logs and try it by yourself to better understand that, as it's an important concept in React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's better not to touch the original state of the object. Instead copying and modifying in that new object the property what we need then passing it to `setState()`. The proper way is using the callback version of setting the state.

Try as the following:

```
setItems(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   item_name: 'the new value'
}));
```

So the function would look like:

```
some_method = (new_item_name) => {
   setItems(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      item_name: new_item_name
   }));
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well, `proper way` is a bit subjective as this is not needed and (imo) more verbose than just using the current state directly

Comment: This worked fine, but please can you explain it with more details?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I believe it's better not to touch the original state of the object. Instead copying and modifying in that new object the property what we need then passing it to `setState()`. Also the code what has been provided in the question is not updating the state as expected.

Comment: Fair enough, I upvoted your answer as it provides more explanation and makes more sens to me now